# Build a Hyper-V template w/ SQL Server 2016 pre-installed

Tags: sql-server-2016

The problem that I've encountered is in renaming the "template" to the "production" server name. SQL Server sys.servers, server_id =0 retains "template", not "production".

The only way around this seems to be to re-install SQL Server -- defeating the purpose of a template.

Note: sp_addserver has been discontinued; sp_addlinkedserver cannot create server_id =0 (local).

Answer (score 1):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/rename-a-computer-that-hosts-a-stand-alone-instance-of-sql-server :

```
sp_dropserver <old_name>;  
GO  
sp_addserver <new_name>, 'local';
GO
```

**Restart the instance of SQL Server.**

For a named instance:

```
sp_dropserver <old_name\instancename>;  
GO  
sp_addserver <new_name\instancename>, 'local';
GO
```

**Restart the instance of SQL Server.**

Note you cannot rename the instance part of the name via this method.